# Does math use diacritics?

Tags: notation, soft-question, math-history

Most languages using Latin script use diacritics to modify letters. In mathematics, it often seems necessary to introduce many symbols and modifiers, such as $f'$ for derivatives or $M^\text{T}$ for the matrix transpose.

However, it seems to me that diacritics are rarely used for this purpose, some examples I can think of are:

- Derivatives in Newton's notation $\dot t$, $\ddot t$.
- Unit vectors written as $\hat v$.
- Complex conjugation denoted $\bar z$.
- Means written as $\bar x$.
- Vectors written as $\vec u$?

Is there a reason that mathematicians don't tend to use diacritics, or is it more common than I realise?

Comment: $\hat f$ is sometimes the Fourier transform of $f.$

Comment: The profinite completion of $G$ is denoted by $\widehat{G}$, the universal covering group of $G$ is denoted by $\widetilde{G}$, and so on. It seems to be more common. Also $\underline{n}$ for $n$-tuples, or $\ddddot{x}$ for ....

Comment: Also [$\tilde f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#As_a_diacritic) sometimes for Fourier transform

Comment: $\hat \mu$ is the observed average after sampling finitely many times from a probability distribution with true average $\mu$. Same with $\hat \sigma$ for standard deviation.

Comment: Often, I find a lot of notational history in math is related to easy of typesetting in the past - what characters were available to a European operating a printing press, and how hard was it to typeset different notations? Here, diacritics certainly existed, but perhaps they were not separate physical items, like there were physical $ö$ characters, but not a separate "umlaut" item which could be applied to any letter. I'm not sure.

Comment: Disclaimer : an incursion outside mathematics : A very interesting use of diacritics is in vietnamian (quoc ngu), which is written with roman characters with a lot of (often combined) [diacritics](https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/vietnamese.htm) to take into account the subtilities of a polytonic language  ;  without that, ambiguity would be constant : same transcription, but different pronunciation because of  rising of lowering tones in particular.

Comment: In fact, in an extended meaning, the most used "diacritics symbols" in mathematics come from the list of usual symbols (letters or characters) : 1) The case of indices, and even multi-indices in **tensor calculus** $a_{ijk}^{lm}$, 2) Cascading indices : indices themselves with indices for **subsequences** $a_{(i_j)}$ (often difficult to read) 3) a case of 2 diacritics in **matrix notations** : combination of inversion and transpose can be denoted $A^{-1T}$ but it is ugly ; one will prefer to place parentheses like that : $(A^{-1})^T$, or $A^{-T}$ (happily the two operations are commutative).

Comment: \bar and \overline are widely used for residue classes when there is a quotient map (i.e. $\bar{r}$ is the coset to the representative $r$). Also for algebraic closures of fields.